# AngularJS + Domain/URL Redirect not working well together

Tags: angularjs, url, spring-mvc, redirect, http-status-code-415

I got a small angularJS based website.

I am hosting it via the service OpenShift on some domain like:

```
bla-blubb.rhcloud.com
```

Which is of course not that pretty, so I ordered a TLD:

```
www.supercoolsite.com
```

from www.united-domains.de. There I habe three possibilities to achieve my goal, see the screen (sorry it is in German - it is: **1) Header redirect, 2) Frame-redirect or 3) URL-Hiding**)
[image]

But none of these seem to work like I want:

**1)** Simply redirects the user, so the ugly URL is shown again.

**2)** Shows my pretty URL, BUT I can't type in like /#/stuff/some/page, it simply does nothing and remains on the start screen. My `ngRoute` `$routeProvider`'s `.when()` doesn't trigger that URL like it normally does.

**3)** Here everything works just fine. I can use Angualr as I'm used to, the above error disappears + the URL is still pretty. BUT: Now I can't send POST Requests with payload to my Java Spring MVC Backend. I get an 415 Error (See second Screen). When using the ugly URL it works perfectly (Everything). It also works using GET methods.

[image]
 *The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method.*

**Does anyone might have an idea? How can I get 2) or 3) working? I don't get what's going wrong.
If code (angular or Spring Controller) is needed, tell me - but as said, it works under DEV and when using the ugly URL.
Thanks!!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution for me was to use another (sub) domain like admin.supercoolsite.com, which does a frame redirect to the `/#/stuff/some/page` URL, automatically triggering my intended behavior.